# Image overlapping a span in another li element

Tags: javascript, html, css

**EDIT: I have created a JS-Fiddle that shows you the code in action and you can see how the caption's text is being overlapped.** https://jsfiddle.net/wj76sv1h/

So I have a list of divs that display images obtained from a Database. This list is created by PHP, but when I have attempted to add a caption, as you can see from the [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QvM9g.png) (sorry I can't include the image directly in the post), it is being overlapped by another Li element's image. The caption is a span tag.

I have attempted to change the z-index of the images and the divs, however it seems like it has no effect. I am also using this code in order to create the grid system using the lis.

```
function createListStyles(rulePattern, rows, cols) {
var rules = [], index = 0;
for (var rowIndex = 0; rowIndex < rows; rowIndex++) {
    for (var colIndex = 0; colIndex < cols; colIndex++) {
        var x = (colIndex * 100) + "%",
            y = (rowIndex * 100) + "%",
            transforms = "{ -webkit-transform: translate3d(" + x + ", " + y + ", 0); transform: translate3d(" + x + ", " + y + ", 0); }";
        rules.push(rulePattern.replace("{0}", ++index) + transforms);
    }
}
var headElem = document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0],
    styleElem = $("<style>").attr("type", "text/css").appendTo(headElem)[0];
if (styleElem.styleSheet) {
    styleElem.styleSheet.cssText = rules.join("\n");
} else {
    styleElem.textContent = rules.join("\n");
}
}
```

If anyone could help me, that would be great. Thanks. This is the html used for the item/caption.

```
<div class="item" id="item-covert"><span>Caption</span> <div id="item-price"> $54.36</div><img class="item-image" src="image.url"></div>
```

Css:

```
.item {
  position: relative
}
.item span {
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    padding: 10px;
    background: rgba(255,255,255,0.99);
    /*top: 20px;
    width: 300px;
    height: 50px;*/
    font-family: Open Sans;
    /*margin-left: 110px;*/
    left: 110px;
}

.item:hover span {
    display: block
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your positioning of the `span` moves it onto the image. Move it ten pixels farther to the right, and it looks fine. https://jsfiddle.net/yak613/5p3uuzfg/
I've taken some liberties with the caption text **:)**
And some suggestions for cool caption colors **:)**

[Live Example](http://sarkelliancreed.comule.com/c/test.php)

Comment: Sadly, this isn't having any affect as the red gun is still overlapping the caption. In my image, the caption is for the item to the left and for some reason the image is overlapping the caption.

Comment: Can you provide a page so i can see the problem? Not a jsfiddle, live page.

Comment: @OscarLawson, what red gun?   maybe you can move the `left:120px` more, say `left:150px;`

Comment: I'm unable to get a domain which sucks. I can send the html, css and the javascript function if you want?

Comment: i have it in a fiddle. did you see it? and did you look at the [live example on my website](http://sarkelliancreed.comule.com/c/test.php)

Comment: It isn't using the JS function and some of the formatting. Here is a jsfiddle, as you can see the image is overlapping the caption. https://jsfiddle.net/wj76sv1h/

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/5xw8bn6x/1/ you might find my way of doing this interesting but it works fine.